# Any rhyme or reason to the names of playing cards?

Tags: traducción

Playing cards A-10 are named expectedingly, *As*, followed by *dos* through *diez*.  But the Jack, Queen and King are called (at least in my experience):

- Jota
- Qüina
- Rey

I can understand calling a card by the letter on it, but only *Jota* does that.

I can understand using a loanword, but only *Qüina* does that.

And I can understand translating the word, but only *Rey* does that.

What gives?

Comment: It's the first time I read *Quena* for the Queen; are you sure about that name? Anyway, I've always heard (and used) *Jota*, *Cu* and *Ka* (the name of the corresponding letter) to refer to the Jack, Queen, and King, respectively.

Comment: I witnessed a card game here in Guadalajara with a Mexican family in which they used those names.  And when I questioned them about the names, they didn't offer any alternate naming scheme.  Of course this doesn't mean these are by any means "official" names :)

Comment: Ah, I see; I just wanted to be sure since I had never heard *Quena* for the Queen before.

Comment: I've always used *Jota*, *Qüina* (note the "ü") and *Rey*.

Comment: @dusan: Thanks, that's probably what I meant, too...

Answer (score 10):

I don't know about Mexico, but in Spain they usually play with two kinds of playing cards, the [French deck](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baraja_francesa) and the [Spanish deck](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baraja_espa%C3%B1ola):

- **French deck**: there are *Corazones* (Hearts), *Picas* (Spades), *Diamantes/Rombos* (Diamonds) and *Tréboles* (Clubs). The cards are named *As* - *Dos* - *Tres* - ... - *Diez* - *Jota/Sota* - *Cu/Reina* - *Ka/Rey*. The name of the Jack (Sota) comes from the similarity to the Spanish 10 card, the sota.
- **Spanish deck**: there are *Bastos*, *Oros*, *Copas* and *Espadas*. The cards are named *As* - *Dos* - *Tres* - ... - *Nueve* - *Sota* - *Caballo* - *Rey*. In most traditional games you take out the eight and nine, and play only with 40 cards.

I know this doesn't answer your question, but these are the names of the cards where I'm from. The names you heard could be very local.  Even here in Spain each family has its own names for the cards, and its own rules for the games. This can cause confusion when playing for the first time with other people because everyone wants to play with his own rules (the rule usually is to play with *las reglas de la casa*).

Comment: +1 Excellent answer.

Comment: BTW, _espadas_ is obviously _Spades_ in English.  The others aren't so clear, but relying on what I found via Reverso and my own two eyes, _bastos_ is _Clubs_.  The suit _oros_ best equates to _Diamonds_, and that leaves _copas_, which, by default (and other good symbolic reasons), best equates to _Hearts_.  Nothing too scientific about that ... just my observations, so if you take issue with my comment here, please bear that in mind.